# How to publish the page in two different locations with two different Page Templates?

Tags: cme, templating, content-manager, custom-resolver

I have a Page named PageA created using PageTemplateA in my publicatioN S070. and there is no any child publications to this publication.

I am publishing the PageA which is using PageTemplateA,But internally while publishing i need to assign with PageTemplateB also and need to publish the pageA with 2 output files with 2 two different templates A and B.

Comment: Your requirement sounds a little bit like an anti-pattern. I'd be interested to know more bout why you wish to do this. Can you add more information to your question?

Comment: The reason why i need  2 Pages is Generally Author will create the page only for Browser But whille publishing i need to publish for Native App version also for Mobile enabled page.Both this pages are mobile enabled pages.

Comment: Thanks. I've added another answer for you based on this extra information

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution, though not one which may satisfy all your requirements, is to copy PageA as PageB, change it's template to PageTemplateB and publish it. If you can determine some rules for when a PageA should have a matching PageB then you can automate the creation using an Event Handler and the publishing using either an Event Handler or a Custom Resolver.

FYI, you cannot have two pages with the same filename in the same Structure Group, regardless of the file extension.

Comment: i can create the Page with different extension or i can append browser and Native at the end of PageName.

Answer (score 1):

If your PageB is intended to be *data* rather than some kind of browsable or editable web page then you could possibly render and publish it as a binary from your PageTemplateA and not need a PageB at all.

Comment: Yes PageB data is different from PageA.Only thing is Author will create the PageA with all component presenatations,But i need to publish the PageB even through there is no any  ageB existts physically. But still i need to publish with different extension internally assigning with one more Page Template .

Comment: You cannot publish a full page from Tridion unless it exists. For your particular use case I would recommend that you use BluePrinting, as per my other answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12530/25

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the additional information added to your answer in the comments... If I understand correctly, you need a mobile page to accompany your web page.

It is unfortunate that this is the case. These days, most implementations can use just the one page to accomplish both purposes due to smart-phone browser capability and responsive frameworks such as Twitter Bootstrap etc.

If the mobile pages can be served from a subdomain or a subfolder (i.e. mobile.example.com or www.example.com/mobile) this would be a **perfect** use case for BluePrinting. You can create a child Publication for mobile from your web Publication (and, if you have a design Publication, a child Publication from that for mobile design) then localise your PageA template to product the required alternate output. This means that your author only has to create and manage one page but they also gain the advantage of being able to localise it. To publish, they can publish from the main web publication and use the advanced tab to also publish in child publications, or you can automate that using an Event Handler.

Comment: Actually my Page is already Mobile Page and again internally there are two version for mobile Page.One is Mobile Browser Page and another is Mobile Native app version page.so i don't want to create any publication again or i don't need to subfolders etc. Only i should see one page in my CME publication,But i when in publish it should publish as two pages.

Comment: I understand what you _want_, but that's not possible - to publish two pages using two templates when only one exists in the Content Manager. You need to consider an alternative option. BluePrinting was, in part, designed with this use exact case in mind - content managed in one place and published in two different ways. You don't need to create anything again, just add an additional publication which inherits everything from the first, including your pages, and gives you the opportunity to change your templates.